# How to read specific string in txt file by using windows batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file

This is the content of my `.txt` file

```
123:456
789:333
```

I'm trying to use `findstr` to read string and search for `789:333`, but it only print fist line `123:456`

As I know, use `cut` can fulfill my requirement in Linux.

In Windows, do we have any method where we can search for a string in a file by using a batch-script?

Comment: What's wrong with `for /f`?

Comment: You are not making any sense. Show us the specific code you used to get that result.

Comment: Please rewrite your question and include code examples.

Answer (score 0):

it is simple. using a for loop.

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /I "789:333" somefile.txt') do echo %%a
```

you can learn a lot about batch file commands by simply opening a `cmd.exe` window and typing `help`

It describes briefly each command and once you find one that you think might work, like let's say `for`, then you simply do `for /?` which will show you help content which will make your life easy.